# How can you connect an external graphics card (eGPU) to 2016 X1 Carbon?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, lenovo-laptop

I am talking about an external graphics where you have a dock that allows you to add in a full sized discrete internal desktop graphics card and use it on an external dock that enhances the power of your laptop.

I have seen people hook up to a variety of ways. Some use the mini PCIe which holds the wifi card. Some plug it into an expressport. Some put it into an hdmi in (although such is rare). Some laptop models such as razer and alienware have external graphics card docks you can buy, but it only works for those models.

X1 Carbon 2016, the bottom is one piece. You could not plug in a wire even if there is a wireless pcie without either leaving the whole bottom off or cutting/drilling a hole in the case - neither option acceptable.

X1 carbon 2016 does not have an expressport slot. Here are the slots it has:

USB 3.0
HDMI (in)
Mini Displayport (in)
Onelink Dock

How would you hook in an eGPU into this laptop?

Comment: For an eGPU to work, you need a PCIe connector. That means Thunderbolt, Express Card, etc. There is not a way to use an eGPU with your X1. It's not practical and I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: What about a USB 3.0 interface?

Comment: Are there USB to PCIe interfaces? (USB based GPU's tend to be a lot less capable than a normal full fledged graphics cards).

Comment: Would it be better than not having it though? Any improvement would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

it is technically possible but you have to run it without the bottom cover and you'll lose WIFI connectivity. Check out the EXP GDC Beast with the mini PCIe connector.

Comment: I realize thunderbolt is optimal but could USB 3.x be used with this (https://www.ebay.com/itm/PCI-E-Express-X1-to-Dual-PCI-Riser-Extend-Adapter-Card-Board-w-1m-USB3-0-Cable/162706785261?_trkparms=aid%3D555019%26algo%3DPL.BANDIT%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20150817211758%26meid%3D5542ec43101e4997b4c17021081da487%26pid%3D100507%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D1%26%26itm%3D162706785261&_trksid=p2045573.c100507.m3226)?

Comment: @www139 good question, would also like to know. edit: i think you are not referring to using usb 3 instead of pci-e? the one you liked to is a pcie card i think.

Answer (score 0):

I've read somewhere that USB 3.0 interface is not suitable for egpu setup due to latency issues. Looks like the only option in your case is to connect egpu through the wifi PCIe slot as suggested by Anon